# how can i post data using Mozilla rest add-on using mailgun api

Tags: json, rest-client, mailgun

I'm using this Mozilla  ADD-ON to post the data in mailgun API
[RestClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)

`Content-Type:application/json`

`URL` I'm using

`https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandbox42924.mailgun.org/messages`

`Json Data` I'm posting

```
[
    {
        "from": "Kaushik <kaushik@gmail.com>"
    },
    {
        "to": "Kaushik <kaushikfb1@gmail.com>"
    },
    {
        "subject": "Hello This is test mail"
    },
    {
        "text": "Testing some Mailgun !"
    },
    {
        "html": "<html>Hello These <h2>contents belongs</h2> to html content</html>"
    }
]
```

**OR**

```
{
    "from": "Kaushik <kaushik@gmail.com>",
    "to": "Kaushik <kaushikfb1@gmail.com>",
    "subject": "Hello This is test mail",
    "text": "Testing some Mailgun !",
    "html": "<html>Hello These <h2>contents belongs</h2> to html content</html>"
}
```

In both cases what I'm getting is

```
{
   "message": "'from' parameter is missing"
}
```

I want to know how i can post the data.

In documentation they have not describe this process.
I'm curious to know how it is working?

Here is the link for the documentation [Click Here](http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples). They are using library for using in each language. If you know the library in detail you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer of this so for the sake of other user so they may find a help from this post in future I'm submitting the answer.

the `url` is this one.

```
https://api.mailgun.net/v2/yourdoamin.com/messages

username = api

password = {your key}
```

Now after that set your `content type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Now post the data. for formatting the data you can use this link [Click Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Demo data format

```
from%3D%27Excited%20User%20%3Cme%40yourdoamin.com%3E%27%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20to%3Dbaz%40example.com%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20to%3Dbar%40example.com%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20subject%3D%27Hello%27%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20text%3D%27Testing%20some%20Mailgun%20awesomness!%27
```